# can I use the method execute() in script Groovy for Jenkins in order to execute shell command?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

can I use the method execute() in script Groovy for Jenkins in order to execute shell command?

What is the best way to execute command shell in Groovy script for Jenkins?

```
class Example { 
   static void main(String[] args) { 
    def map = [:]
    def array = new File('deployable.txt') as String[];
    def versionDate = "snapshot"

        
      for(String i in array) { 
         
         String[] splitedPath =i.split("/");
         int indexFilename = splitedPath.length -1
            
            String  fileName = splitedPath [indexFilename]
           
            println(fileName)
            String []name =fileName.split('.t')
            String nameOri =name[0]
            println(nameOri)
            nameOri = nameOri+"-"+versionDate+".txt"
           
         map.put(i, nameOri )

      }
      map.each{entry -> 
      println "$entry.key: $entry.value"
      def source ="$entry.key"
      def dest="$entry.value"
      
        def command = 'touch '+source
        println command
        command.execute()
        command = 'mv '+source +' test/'+dest
        command.execute()


      } 
      
   } 
}
```